# How do I get values from a ActiveRecord CollectionProxy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i'm having trouble looping through a collection property to get out values.

This is my proxy

```
<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Product id: 12, name: "test", cost_in_cents: 4400, created_at: "2014-10-31 17:18:58", updated_at: "2014-10-31 17:18:58", subscription: nil, product_type: "One Time">, #<Product id: 14, name: "aggg", cost_in_cents: 1400, created_at: "2014-10-31 17:28:19", updated_at: "2014-10-31 17:28:19", subscription: nil, product_type: "One Time">]>
```

I want to be able to loop through all of the objects in the proxy like this.

```
my_collection_proxy.each do |c| c.name end
```

But that doesn't seem to be working.  How do I get the value of each name in the proxy?

Output:

```
@order.products.each do |a| a.name end
=> [#<Product id: 12, store_front_id: 8, name: "test", cost_in_cents: 4400, created_at: "2014-10-31 17:18:58", updated_at: "2014-10-31 17:18:58", subscription: nil, product_type: "One Time">, #<Product id: 14, store_front_id: 8, name: "aggg", cost_in_cents: 1400, created_at: "2014-10-31 17:28:19", updated_at: "2014-10-31 17:28:19", subscription: nil, product_type: "One Time">]
```

What I want my output to look like:

```
=> test
=> aggg
```

Comment: So when I loop through the proxy, i'm not getting the individual names back on new lines.  I'm getting the whole object.  I updated my question with an output.

Comment: @joe where are you running `@order.products.each do |a|
       a.name
    end` in rail console?

Comment: Yes it's in my rails console.  @engineersmnky I tried all of those, and i'm getting the same output.

Comment: What about `@orders.products{|prod| puts prod.each(&:name)}`?

Answer (score 17):

If you're trying to pull all the names into an array, you should use Enumerable#collect:

```rb
names = @order.products.collect(&:name)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this in your rails console:

```
@order.products.each do |p|
  puts p.name
end
# => test
# => aggg
```

`puts` will display product's name(`p.name`) and adds a newline after executing.

Comment: Hahaha. Totally didn't realize he was running this in the console. This is the right answer @joe you must output the results using puts `#each` just returns the original object.

Answer (score 0):

Used `@record.property.map(&:to_s)`.